# Generating random numbers that are log-normally distributed

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-generation, lognormal-distribution

Even though I don't quite understand why and how this works, I appreciate how simple it is to generate a set of numbers which are Poisson distributed:

```
public static int getPoisson(double lambda) {
    double l = Math.exp(-lambda);
    double p = 1.0;
    int k = 0;

    do {
        k++;
        p *= Math.random();
    } while (p > l);

    return k - 1;
}
```

This "generating" function is basically from [this book](http://luc.devroye.org/chapter_ten.pdf) were I also find generating functions for the binomial and the geometric distribution.

But I did not find a simple generating function for the log-normal distribution. Either the author calls this distribution the "logarithmic series distribution" (then the generating function would not be simple), or it is missing. In the latter case I am looking for some pseudo-code.

Comment: You can probably find details about how to create a random number generator for a normal distribution; then you just have to take the exponent of it.

Comment: @jwimberley: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: The logarithmic series distribution is a completely different beast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the log-normal distribution is defined as the distribution of exp(X) where X is a random variable following a normal distribution, you need only find details about how to sample a random number from a normal distribution, and take its exponent.

Comment: Sorry, but don't you mean "take its logarithm"?

Comment: No, I do not. If If X is log-normally distributed, then log(X) is normally distributed, which is what you are probably thinking of. But I'm describing generating a normally distributed Y=log(X) directly. You couldn't take the logarithm of a normally distributed value, anyways, since the normal distribution has support on the negative real numbers, outside the domain of the logarithm.

Comment: The term _lognormal_ is in a sense backward as a lognormal distribution is, as said, an exponentiated normal. The lognormal is named for what you can do with it -- take logarithms, and you get a normal -- rather than for what you need to do to get it. Although it would be appealing to start all over again with statistical terminology -- the term _normal_ is itself a source of much confusion and misunderstanding -- in practice we have to muddle through and hope that with slow campaigns some usages will fade away and better terms will take their place.

Comment: Devroye discusses generating from the normal distribution in chapter 9. In the section on normal distributions, an exercise about lognormal distributions (p. 392) mentions this approach, and also hints at a faster/more direct approach to generating lognormal variates.